# Simple JS code not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to learn, so if you can just point out the mistake without actually telling me that would be great but if it requires the solution I am fine with that too - I would just like an explanation.

Goal is to click the button and have it move to a random position. I am not getting errors but I am not getting console.log output either. If I move the console.log out of the function I do get the output.

```
var buttonState = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var maxWidth = screen.width;
var maxHeight = screen.height;
var screenWidth = 0;
var screenHeight = 0;
// Find max width and height of screen and set variables to random number within parameters
function moveButton() {
    "use strict";
    screenWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxWidth - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    screenHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - 1 + 1)) + 1;
}
buttonState.onClick = function () {
    "use strict";
    movebutton();
    buttonState.style.left = screenWidth.page + "px";
    buttonState.style.top = screenHeight.page + "px";
    console.log(screenWidth);
    console.log(screenHeight);         
};
```

Comment: I've found four errors: The two first: Remind that, in javascript, _letter case in identifiers_ is important. Then, one error related to the @vinayakj's suggestion. And last, debug the values you are actually setting to the `left` and `top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> buttonState.onClick
> ```

The property name is `onclick` (with a lower-case `c`). JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: OK great. I also caught a few more errors from your help. Thanks so much. It works now.